# Virtual Desktop & Virtual Machine

Tags: privacy

What is the difference between virtual machine and virtual desktop?

KOMODO Internet Security, for example, offers virtual desktop, and there's a stealth program there.

If software sends the same identifier, hostname, tracking cookie or similar does VM or VD prevent the leaks?

Comment: I think you mean [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com/), and they [should not be taken serious anymore](http://www.infoworld.com/t/authentication/weaknesses-in-ssl-certification-exposed-comodo-security-breach-593).

Answer (score 1):

1. A virtual machine is an operating system installed on a virtualization software such as [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and [VMware Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Player). It emulates the existing hardware of the host machine on which it runs. This means a software running on a virtual machine will "think" it is running on a "normal" computer resources. You can do on it all what you do on a usual computer with a running computer system. It is used for testing applications, emulating networks and even testing applications for the presence of malware as [SpyProxy](https://www.usenix.org/conference/16th-usenix-security-symposium/spyproxy-execution-based-detection-malicious-web-content) is functionning.
2. COMODO and other virtual desktops are a typical cases of a virtual machine. For example, if you run a browser on a virtual desktop, you won't have any cookies saved unlike it on a virtual machine. However, it is more intended to browse the internet against web malware attacks.
3. While they are both virtualization concepts (a computer inside a computer), a virtual desktop runs only ONE virtual machine, whereas you can install and run several virtual machines on a virtualization system such as VirtualBox.